# Reading text file with multiple columns with logic

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm reading a text file that has multiple columns and I'm storing the information in an array

File looks like this

```
Player   |   Team
---------| ---------
PlayerA  |  Team1
PlayerA  |  Team2
PlayerB  |  Team3
PlayerC  |  Team4
PlayerC  |  Team5
```

As you see each player has multiple teams. I am trying to read this file line by line so that at the end of the file I have a List with three players (A, B, and C) and each having their corresponding teams.

Classes:

```
Player - with Name and List<Team> (getter setter for both)
Team   - with Name (getter and setter)
```

I can't figure out the logic of when to create the Player and Team classes and keep account for when the player name has changed

Comment: Just maintain a Map of <Person, List<Team>>, and keep on adding the objects.

Comment: I guess that with *create* you actually mean *instantiate* an object of that class... In that case what you mean with that the player name can change? Can it change as you read the file? E.g. An already existing team appears with a different player name?

Comment: Is the name in Player a String?

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your `person` and `team` inside two classes `Person` and `Team`..

Then, You can use a `Map<Person, List<Team>>` to maintain various teams for each Person..

```
Map<Person, List<Team>> mapping = new HashMap<>();

// Read each line from file..

// Get Person and Team object..

// Assuming that you have your `Person` object in person and `Team` object in team

// You need a Comparator for `Person` class to check for `containment`..
if (mapping.contains(person)) {

    // Person already exist.. Update the list of Team he has
    mapping.get(person).add(team);

} else {

    // New entry.. create a new list.. and add it to map..
    List<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<>();
    teamList.add(team);
    mapping.put(person, teamList);
}
```

**NOTE** : - You need to have a `Comparator` for your `Person` class to be compared..

I think I have given you a base to work upon.. Rest you need to workaround.. How to populate your object.. How to implement Comparator.. and all that..

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would not question the validity of the model proposed but ... does not make more sense that the teams are those that have many players rather than the opposite?

Anyhow, assuming that the player name cannot be changed by a team appearing again with a different player name:

```
  BufferedReader input = ...;
  Map<String,Player> playersByName = new HashMap<String,Player>();

  String line;
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     String playerName;
     String teamName;
     // code to parse the player and team names from 'line' comes here.

     Player player = playersByName.get(playerName);
     if (player == null)
       playersByName.put(playerName,player = new Player(playerName));

     Team team = new Team(teamName);
     if (!player.getTeams().contains(team)) 
        player.getTeams().add(team);
  }
```

The code assumes that the Player constructor creates an empty list of teams.

Although the above will work using a list to hold the teams for a player I would suggest that you use a `Set` instead for efficiency if the number of teams that player has can be quite big.  In that case you do not need the last conditional, you could add directly.

Even better if you hide the `List` or `Set` implementation entirely and you add operations to manipulate the team list safely within the Player class.

Remeber that if you use a (hashed) `Set` solution (hidden or exposed) you'll need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` functions appropriately in the `Team` class (delegating them on its name would work very well).